# find the conic curve through given points

Tags: conic-sections, curves, algebraic-curves

I am trying to find a conic curve that passes through $[0:1:2]$ and intersects the conic curve $F =x_1^2 + 4x_1x_2  + 4x_0x_2 -x_0^2$ at the point $[1:1:0]$ with multiplicity $4$. Since I am given $5$ points (counted with multiplicity) there should be a unique conic that fulfils the requested properties.

Projective conic curves are of the form: $Ax_1^2 + Bx_1x_2 + Cx_2^2 + Dx_1x_0 + Ex_2x_0 + Fx_0^2$.

Since it has to go through the points $[0:1:2]$ and $[1:1:0]$ I get $A + 2B + 4C = 0$ and $A+D+F = 0$.

However, from here I don't know how I can proceed and how I can use the fact, that the intersection multiplicity in $[1:1:0]$ has to be $4$.

Comment: The point $[0:1:0]$ is not on the conic $F=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks! I have changed the point.

Comment: Still no good. How can intersection multiplicity be $2$? $3$? $4$?

Comment: @TedShifrin can you please tell me where the problem is? 
i know that by Bezout‘s theorem the sum of the multiplicities of the intersection points is equal to 4. So I know that if one intersection point has multiplicity 4, there are no more intersection points.

Comment: Sorry, I was making two separate points. Your point $[1:1:0]$ is still not on the curve. My separate question was asking you to describe the geometry of the two curves that accounts for the various intersection multiplicities.

Comment: @TedShifrin now the point should be on the curve. Geometrically, this means that there is than one intersection point close to P when moving the curve a little

Comment: If two curves meet (simply) tangentially at $P$ and $P$ is a smooth point of both, what is the intersection multiplicity at $P$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Then the multiplicity will be 1, right?

Comment: $F=(x_1+x_0)(4x_2+x_1-x_0)$